# Need Help, New to PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm somewhat new to php and MySQL.  I'm going through a tutorial and get the above message when i call the function below.

```
<?php
function get_subject_by_id($subject_id){
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE id=" . $subject_id . "LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($result_set);
    //if no rowes are returned, fetch array will return false
    if ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
        return $subject;
    } else { 
        return NULL;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What message are you getting?

Comment: Please **do not** use the obsolete `mysql` extension. Use `PDO` instead (or `mysqli`)

Comment: If you are just starting, you should be using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as the `mysql_*` extensions have been deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

`$query = "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE id=" . $subject_id . "LIMIT 1";`

should be

`$query = "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE id=" . $subject_id . " LIMIT 1";`

Notice the space before `LIMIT 1`.

But we still don't know exactly what your problem is because you haven't specified.

Comment: Let's add an `intval()` call to avoid the SQL injection hole

Comment: And get rid of `mysql_*` extensions :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to add the error message.

Database connection failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PDO version of the same code, and some good reading on PDO

Sets up your connection and then you can use PDO's much safer querying functions like so:

```
function get_subject_by_id($subject_id){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'name_of_database';
    $user = 'user_name';
    $pass = 'User_password';
    try{
        $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
    }catch(PDOException $e){  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = $DB->prepare($query);
    //Include the variables to pass with the query
    $result_set->execute(array($subject_id));
    //You should modify this function to use PDO as well
    confirm_query($result_set);
    //if no rowes are returned, fetch array will return false
    if ($result_set->rowCount()) {
        return $subject;
    } else { 
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

And Here's some reading:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php